# iOS In App Purchase Fails Silently in Production

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase, app-store

So I've tested my application's In App Purchase content at length during development using the Sandbox mode.

For some reason now that the application is live in the App Store when clicking the purchase button nothing happens at all.

It looks like the Apple review team was able to successfully complete a purchase based on server logs (could be wrong about this tho).

I'm using [SwiftyStoreKit](https://github.com/bizz84/SwiftyStoreKit) to handle in app purchases.

Any ideas why it would work perfectly during development and in sandbox mode and not even do anything when calling the `SwiftyStoreKit.purchaseProduct` method in production?

If I had to guess it has to do with the App Store servers needing time to process everything. It took a little bit to appear on the App Store. But I'm not completely confident that is the issue.

Comment: I'm about to add IAP to an app, so I can't (yet) help you. (1) Have you checked into any issues with SwiftyStoreKit? Hopefully the author there may be of some help. (2) I wouldn't hold out much hope for latency with the App Store. It does take time to propagate an app update across the regions, but an IAP is - IMHO - too tightly integrated with an app to *not* propagate *with* the app.

Comment: @dfd Defiantly makes sense about the latency. That's why I'm not super confident that is the issue. Sadly there isn't a very good way to debug this because it's not like a crash that I'll get reports for, and I don't believe there is a way to attach the debugger to a production application to debug it that way.

Comment: @dfd Does look like an App Store propagation issue. Seems to be working now. Thanks so much!

Comment: That's nice to know. I'll expect that in another week when it's my turn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the sudden this seems to be working. It now asks for the Touch ID to confirm purchase. So it looks like it was an App Store server propagation issue.

Comment: Hi Charlie, I know this is old but do you remember how long it took for the purchases to start working after your app and IAPs were approved? Thanks!

Comment: @hujasonx I think it was roughly a day.