# SKProductsRequest returns zero products on AppStore build

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase

Sandbox works perfect, In App Purchases got approved and update just confirmed and released.
Contracts and Agreements are confirmed as well.

But when I open purchase screen in my app from AppStore - application crashes and based on Crashlytics report it happens on SKProductsRequest response because result comes as empty.

TestFlight build works fine as well.

My product identifiers are like that (perfectly matches ids from iTunes connect):

```
let productId = Set(["1year", "1month"])
```

And request looks like:

```
let request = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: productId)
request.delegate = ProductsRequestDelegate(parent: self, success: success, failure: failure)
request.start()
```

Crash happens here accordingly to crashlytics report:

```
private func getMonthlySubscription() -> SKProduct {
    return InAppPurchase.instance.productsMap.values.reversed().first!
}
```

Is there any way to fix that?
It's super weird because app was tested very well and issue is not reproducible on Xcode and TestFlight builds.
Even Apple was not able to reproduce it during review and after release we got this sad surprise.

Thank you so much for any help/advices with issue!

Comment: I could be totally wrong. But I had a similar problem due to Apple's servers just not updating very fast. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43359067/ios-in-app-purchase-fails-silently-in-production

Comment: @CharlieFish thank you! so the issue should be resolved without any changes? how long it was in your case?

Comment: For me it was a couple hours. I'm not sure how long your app has been in the app store. But for me it was a couple of hours, but I would assume it could take as long as a day.

Comment: @CharlieFish awesome, it was just resolved, works perfect, just made first purchase. Could you please add your answer as Answer below? so I'll be able to mark it as Correct Answer.

Comment: Done! And I marked it as a duplicate as well just incase someone wants some more information. Happy coding!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has to do with App Store server propagation. I have seen this issue take between an hour or so to a day to update. Apple's servers just take time to update.